# How to register my Application on Foursquare

Tags: foursquare

I am new to making applications using Foursquare API. While registering my application on developers.foursquare.com it asked me to type 
Download / welcome page url:eg www.example.com 
Your privacy policy url:
and Callback url 
I am simply using my Xampp server to run my application. So what all things I need to fill in there.

Answer (score 1):

The callback URL is the URL that foursquare will make requests to in order to authenticate users, so this must be a URL on your server that can handle OAuth authenticate requests.

The welcome page URL and privacy policy URLs are linked to from the authenticate dialog the user sees when they try to authenticate your app. They should provide information about your app so users can make an informed decision about whether to connect your app or not.